# How do I make a reaction log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wan't to make a reaction log for my server, but I keep getting `undefined`.

Here's the code:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async function (messageReaction, user, message) {
  const channel = messageReaction.channel
  let reaction = await client.channels.fetch('CHANNEL ID');
  reaction.send(`A reaction has been added to a message by ${user} \nin ${channel}`);
});
```

Comment: Which variable returns undefined?

Comment: Channel is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the property `channel` from `messageReaction.message`

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async function (messageReaction, user, message) {
  const channel = messageReaction.message.channel
  let reaction = await client.channels.fetch('CHANNEL ID');
  reaction.send(`A reaction has been added to a message by ${user} \nin ${channel}`);
});
```

Documentation on [MessageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd)